# Showing duplicate keys on antd pie charts

Tags: reactjs, charts, antd

Im using an antd pie chart with the following data. Is there a way to separate the two 'test1' even if they have the same key?

```html
const data = [
    {
      type: 'test1',
      value: 21,
    },
    {
      type: 'test2',
      value: 25,
    },
    {
      type: 'test1',
      value: 18,
    },
  ];
```

[what the chart looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diPzH.png)